# write file with ionic, plug in Phone, copy away?

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I've just seen that there exists a [cordova extionsion](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) to write files in ionic.

But. What am i supposed to do with it? I mean a Usecase would be *"create File, Plug-in Mobile, Copy to to Computer"* but this I guess isn't supported by iOS at all.

So my questions are:

**What is `$cordovaFile` meant for in ionic?**

**Is it possible to to realize the above Usecase in android even though it's clearly not in iOS?**

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the github page:

> This plugin implements a File API allowing read/write access to files residing on the device.

Maybe you would want to download an image and save it to the sd card for example (you would need filetransfer plugin to download the image). More info about the plugin you can find [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file).